# Why can't I run jupyter-annotator code in Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, annotations, google-colaboratory

cell 1

```
!pip install jupyter-annotator
```

cell 2

```
from jupyter_innotater import *
import numpy as np, os
```

cell 3

```
images = os.listdir('./foods/')
targets = np.zeros((len(images), 4)) # Initialise bounding boxes as x,y = 0,0, width,height = 0,0
Innotater( ImageInnotation(images, path='./foods'), BoundingBoxInnotation(targets) )
```

I have a problem when I try to run the third cell my kernel restarts in Colab .

Answer (score 0):

Colab does not support custom jupyter widgets yet.

So, you need to wait until it has support.

See [issue #60](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/60)